# Why does Django Admin Panel draw my coordinates for Brooklyn, NY in Antarctica?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-admin, postgis

I have a Django app running on PostGreSQL with PostGIS extension.

In this app, I have created an Address object which has a PointField representing an address in Brooklyn, NY. It is (properly) geocoded as `POINT (40.7025627000000014 -73.9906821999999949)`

But when I click the drill-down view on this instance in the Admin Panel, it shows me a map with a yellow circle in Antarctica. Why?? Even when I zoom in or zoom out on the map, the circle stays in the exact same spot on the screen regardless of what part of the map is showing. Why? And how do I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that you have latitude and longitude reversed. That POINT is an `(x,y)` value (i.e. the first part is horizontal/longitude and the second component is vertical/latitude) but geographic coordinates are generally represented as `(latitude, longitude)` pairs. Somewhere you need to reverse the order of the coordinates in your POINT before it gets to your map.